# How to apply the same settings to different Github repositories?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to apply settings like:

- Allow only squash merge for pull requests
- Disable wiki
- Disable issues
- ...

and other options you can configure on the `settings` menu.

I want to change it for a group of hundreds repositories in the same organisation.

I don't want to use the UI for that. In the best scenario I would like to capture this configuration in code.

I started to play with the API for that. However, I would like to know if anyone here have faced the problem and have any tips about it?

Thank you.